# Cognex creating own application from scratch

Tags: c#, cognex

what do they mean about

port.DtrEnable = true,

https://support.cognex.com/docs/dmst_616SR1/web/EN/Comms_Prog_Manual/Content/Topics/PDF/DMCAP/DMCCApplicationDevelopment.htm

Where do I put this code on the sample code?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably working with COM ports.

you need import

```
using System.IO.Ports;
```

And when you create a [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.8) you should set the property

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort();
serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
```